# Identity tables not being created

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core

In my `ConfigureServices` I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    //...
}
```

And in `Configure` I have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseIdentity();

    //...
}
```

When I `dnx . add migration addingIdentity`, I don't get any of the identity tables created in the new migrations file (so the `apply` doesn't do anything).

What's missing?

Comment: Well, no - because the new `addingIdentity` file in the migrations folder is empty - nothing in the `Up` or `Down` methods. So it wouldn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was because my DbContext wasn't inheriting from IdentityDbContext...

```
public sealed class Context : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
```